# Solve equation $\sin x + \cos x= i$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Could anyone help with following equation?

$$\sin(x) + \cos(x) = i$$

Solution either in **C** or **R**. First of all, sorry for dummy question. And even dummier followup. What is wrong with following reasoning?

$(\sin(x) + \cos(x))^2 = i^2$

$((\sin(x))^2 + (\cos(x))^2 + 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = -1$

$2\sin(x)\cos(x) = -2$

$\sin(2x) = -2$

Which is out of sine codomain ): ?

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: If you allow complex arguments (which you must) then $-2$ is *not* out of the codomain. $-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$ holds only for real numbers.

Comment: Maybe it's better to take something like
$$
\cos z = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz} }{2} \qquad 
\sin z = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz} }{2i}
$$

Comment: Another option is to use complex exponentials since

$$ \sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}, \qquad \cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}.$$

Plugging these expressions into the original equation, you have a quadratic equation in $e^{ix}$ after some manipulation which can be solved via the quadratic formula.

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot. That was very helpful. Using exponentials, substitution and quadratic equation leads to solution. I'm just not able to put the final natural logarithms to some nice form /:

Answer (score 2):

To avoid spurious solutions from squaring the equation, proceed as follows. Note
$$\sin x+\cos x= \sqrt2\sin (x+\frac\pi4+2\pi n)=
i \sqrt2 \sinh[-i(x+\frac\pi4+2\pi n)]=i 
$$
which leads to

$$-i(x+\frac\pi4+2\pi n)=\sinh^{-1}\frac1{\sqrt2}=\frac12\ln(2+\sqrt3)
$$
and the solutions
$$x = \frac i2\ln(2+\sqrt3)-\frac\pi4-2\pi n$$

Comment: Very neat solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Smrduty skunk - you’re welcome